# Mockito does not mock the class ThreadLocal

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I am using a JUnit 5.7.0 and n Mockito 3.6.28. When I try to mock the class ThreadLocal with the code below

```
ThreadLocal threadLocalMock = Mockito.mock(ThreadLocal.class);
```

I receive the following error message:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.logging.LogRecord
> at org.junit.platform.commons.logging.LoggerFactory$DelegatingLogger.createLogRecord(LoggerFactory.java:170)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.logging.LoggerFactory$DelegatingLogger.log(LoggerFactory.java:146)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.logging.LoggerFactory$DelegatingLogger.warn(LoggerFactory.java:100)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.lambda$notifyEach$1(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:71)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.notifyEach(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:65)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.access$200(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:32)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.executionFinished(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:108)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ExecutionListenerAdapter.executionFinished(ExecutionListenerAdapter.java:56)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:113)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

Is there any way to resolve this problem ?